The LPS22HB pressure sensor doesn't work
I recently designed a PCB that has an STM32F405RGT6 as the MCU and incorporates a LPS22HB pressure sensor. I attempted to develop the drivers for this sensor and verify the WHO_AM_I address; however, I encountered an issue where the read byte returns 0xFF instead of 0xB1. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could review both the hardware and software components of my PCB to identify any potential issues. Given the small size of the package and the proximity of the pins, I suspect that inadequate soldering may be the cause of the problem. However, since the package is HLGA-10L, the pads are not visible once the sensor is soldered, which is why I have not included a photo of the soldered sensor.
The header file of the sensor:
#ifndef INC_DRIVERS_LPS22HB_H_
#define INC_DRIVERS_LPS22HB_H_

#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"

#define INTERRUPT_CFG     0x0B
#define THS_P_L           0x0C
#define FIFO_CTRL         0x14
#define REF_P_XL          0x15
#define REF_P_L           0x16
#define REF_P_H           0x17
#define RPDS_L            0x18
#define RPDS_H            0x19
#define RES_CONF          0x1A
#define INT_SOURCE        0x25
#define FIFO_STATUS       0x26
#define STATUS            0x27
#define PRESS_OUT_XL      0x28
#define PRESS_OUT_L       0x29
#define PRESS_OUT_H       0x2A
#define TEMP_OUT_L        0x2B
#define TEMP_OUT_H        0x2C
#define LPFP_RES          0x33

typedef struct {

SPI_HandleTypeDef *spiHandle;
GPIO_TypeDef *csPinBank;
uint16_t csPin;

float temp;
float pres;

float altitude;

}LPS22HB;


uint8_t LPS22HB_init(LPS22HB *LPS,
                 SPI_HandleTypeDef *spiHandle,
                 GPIO_TypeDef *csPinBank,
                 uint16_t csPin);

uint8_t LPS22HB_ReadRegister(LPS22HB *LPS, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t *data);
uint8_t LPS22HB_WriteRegister(LPS22HB *LPS, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t data);

#endif

The c file of the sensor:
#include "LPS22HB.h"

#include <math.h>

uint8_t LPS22HB_init(LPS22HB *LPS,
                 SPI_HandleTypeDef *spiHandle,
                 GPIO_TypeDef *csPinBank,
                 uint16_t csPin) {

LPS->spiHandle = spiHandle;
LPS->csPinBank = csPinBank;
LPS->csPin = csPin;

HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LPS->csPinBank, LPS->csPin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
HAL_Delay(10);

uint8_t status = 0;
uint8_t regData = 0;

status += LPS22HB_ReadRegister(LPS, WHO_AM_I, &regData);

if(regData != 0xB1) {
    printf("WHO_AM_I value: 0x%X\n", regData);
    return 255;
}
return status;
}

uint8_t LPS22HB_ReadRegister(LPS22HB *LPS, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t *data){

uint8_t txBuf[2] = {(regAddr | 0x80), 0x00};
uint8_t rxBuf[2];

HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LPS->csPinBank, LPS->csPin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
uint8_t status = (HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(LPS->spiHandle, txBuf, rxBuf, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY) == HAL_OK);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LPS->csPinBank, LPS->csPin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

if(status == 1) {

    *data = rxBuf[1];

}

return status;
}

The main file(STM32cubeIDE):
#include "main.h"
#include "usb_device.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "LPS22HB.h"
#include "stdio.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi2;
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi3;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

LPS22HB LPS;

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI2_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI3_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
int _write(int file, char *ptr, int len)
{
int DataIdx;
for(DataIdx=0; DataIdx<len; DataIdx++)
{
    ITM_SendChar(*ptr++);
}
return len;
}
/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
* @brief  The application entry point.
* @retval int
*/
int main(void)
{
/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

/* USER CODE END 1 */

/* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

/* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
HAL_Init();

/* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

/* USER CODE END Init */

/* Configure the system clock */
SystemClock_Config();

/* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

/* USER CODE END SysInit */

/* Initialize all configured peripherals */
MX_GPIO_Init();
MX_TIM2_Init();
MX_SPI1_Init();
MX_SPI2_Init();
MX_SPI3_Init();
MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
uint8_t a = LPS22HB_init(&LPS, &hspi3, GPIOB, SPI3_BAR_CS_Pin);

printf("%u\n", a);

/* USER CODE END 2 */

/* Infinite loop */
/* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
while (1)
{
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
}
/* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
* @brief System Clock Configuration
* @retval None
*/
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{ 
RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

/** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
*/
__HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
__HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

/** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
* in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
*/
RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 168;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
{
Error_Handler();
}

/** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
*/
RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                          |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK)
{
Error_Handler();
}
}

/**
* @brief SPI1 Initialization Function
* @param None
* @retval None
*/
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{

/* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 0 */

/* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 0 */

/* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 1 */

/* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 1 */
/* SPI1 parameter configuration*/
hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
{
Error_Handler();
}
/* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 2 */

/* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 2 */

}

/**
* @brief SPI2 Initialization Function
* @param None
* @retval None
*/
static void MX_SPI2_Init(void)
{

/* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 0 */

/* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 0 */

/* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 1 */

/* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 1 */
/* SPI2 parameter configuration*/
hspi2.Instance = SPI2;
hspi2.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
hspi2.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
hspi2.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
hspi2.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
hspi2.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
hspi2.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
hspi2.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
hspi2.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
hspi2.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
hspi2.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
hspi2.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi2) != HAL_OK)
{
Error_Handler();
}
/* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 2 */

/* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 2 */

}

/**
* @brief SPI3 Initialization Function
* @param None
* @retval None
*/
static void MX_SPI3_Init(void)
{

/* USER CODE BEGIN SPI3_Init 0 */

/* USER CODE END SPI3_Init 0 */

/* USER CODE BEGIN SPI3_Init 1 */

/* USER CODE END SPI3_Init 1 */
/* SPI3 parameter configuration*/
hspi3.Instance = SPI3;
hspi3.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
hspi3.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
hspi3.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
hspi3.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
hspi3.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
hspi3.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
hspi3.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_8;
hspi3.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
hspi3.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
hspi3.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
hspi3.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi3) != HAL_OK)
{
Error_Handler();
}
/* USER CODE BEGIN SPI3_Init 2 */

/* USER CODE END SPI3_Init 2 */

}

/**
* @brief TIM2 Initialization Function
* @param None
* @retval None
*/
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

/* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 0 */

/* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 0 */

TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

/* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 1 */

/* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
htim2.Instance = TIM2;
htim2.Init.Prescaler = 0;
htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
htim2.Init.Period = 4294967295;
htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
{
Error_Handler();
}
sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
{
Error_Handler();
}
sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
{
Error_Handler();
}
if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
{
Error_Handler();
}
if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_3) != HAL_OK)
{
Error_Handler();
}
/* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 2 */

/* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 2 */
HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim2);

}

/**
* @brief GPIO Initialization Function
* @param None
* @retval None
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

/* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
__HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
__HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
__HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
__HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

/*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_STATUS_GPIO_Port, LED_STATUS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

/*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, SPI1_CS_Pin|FLASH_NHOLD_Pin|FLASH_NWP_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

/*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI2_NCS_GPIO_Port, SPI2_NCS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

/*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI3_MAG_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI3_MAG_CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

/*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI3_BAR_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI3_BAR_CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

/*Configure GPIO pins : LED_STATUS_Pin SPI1_CS_Pin FLASH_NHOLD_Pin FLASH_NWP_Pin */
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LED_STATUS_Pin|SPI1_CS_Pin|FLASH_NHOLD_Pin|FLASH_NWP_Pin;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/*Configure GPIO pins : INT1_IMU_Pin INT_MAG_Pin INT_BAR_Pin */
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = INT1_IMU_Pin|INT_MAG_Pin|INT_BAR_Pin;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/*Configure GPIO pin : SPI2_NCS_Pin */
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = SPI2_NCS_Pin;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
HAL_GPIO_Init(SPI2_NCS_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/*Configure GPIO pin : SPI3_MAG_CS_Pin */
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = SPI3_MAG_CS_Pin;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
HAL_GPIO_Init(SPI3_MAG_CS_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/*Configure GPIO pin : SPI3_BAR_CS_Pin */
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = SPI3_BAR_CS_Pin;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
HAL_GPIO_Init(SPI3_BAR_CS_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
* @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
* @retval None
*/
void Error_Handler(void)
{
/* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
/* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
__disable_irq();
while (1)
{
}
/* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
* @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
*         where the assert_param error has occurred.
* @param  file: pointer to the source file name
* @param  line: assert_param error line source number
* @retval None
*/
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
/* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
/* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
 ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
/* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

The SPI configuration:


The CS pin configuration:

The schematic of the sensor:

The whole schematic:

The layout of the sensor:



What type and length of cable? and please show us the signal integrity on DSO at each end of MOSI MISO & CLK

You should do more debugging yourself with a scope or logic analyser if you suspect "inadequate soldering", even though the pins are covered by the chip package, you should still be able to probe the pins that connect to the MCU. Other than that there is nothing we could comment about. It is a little bit too late for software and hardware review, this should be done before the making of the PCB. Did you test your software with a MCU development board and sensor breakout board before you making the PCB?

Judge from the photo of the PCB that you post before, I must say it is very likely a soldering issue than anything else, so the schematic, PCB layout and the software are not relevant. Order stencil and invest on a heat gun or reflow station if you want to design PCB.

@hcheung I agree that it's on me to see what went wrong, but I wanted to ask just 2 questions if you can help me. Do you think the traces could be the problem? I tried to space them as best as I could, but there are still some traces that cross each other. Could that cause the issue? What could it mean if, when I connected the oscilloscope probe to GND and CS pin, I could read the address 0xB1 properly? I also tested with a digital multimeter and, with only one cable of the digital multimeter (I wanted to see what happens if I connected CS pin to GND), it also worked.

@hcheung I think this might indicate the sensor is properly soldered and responsive, but there are some issues with the CS pin maybe? I would be very grateful for a response! Thank you!

What kind of problem you are suspecting that caused by the traces? From what you described, it sounds like there are some dry joint somewhere or not all the grounds are connected. You should at least clean-up the PCB first, it looks horrible with all the flux and tiny solder balls everywhere.

@hcheung it took me a while, but finally I solved the problem and I read the register correctly, so I wanted to let you know you were right, it was indeed the soldering. The cs pin configured on the STM32 MCU wasn't properly soldered to the pad.
